# eosio.cdt 1.3.2 indexed_by error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression

Tags: smart-contract, c++, eosio.cdt

I'm trying to shift my contract and build it with the latest CDT, v1.3.2.

The transition docs say to use the new ""_n name constructor but it doesn't appear to be working.

I have:

```
typedef multi_index<"settings"_n, setting, 
    indexed_by<"setting_key"_n, const_mem_fun<setting, uint64_t, &setting::by_setting_key>>
> setting_index;
```

But I get a compile error:

error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression

indexed_by<"setting_key"_n, const_mem_fun>

```
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out.

In case anyone else has this issue. Looks like the index name can't have an underscore in it.

Changed to:

```
typedef multi_index<"settings"_n, setting, 
    indexed_by<"settingkey"_n, const_mem_fun<setting, uint64_t, &setting::by_setting_key>>
> setting_index;
```

Comment: bloody things can't contain capitals either. must be all lowercase